# Is there a way to convert a string into an int *?

Tags: c++11

Is there a way to convert a string that the user inputs into an int * in C++?

```
int * add;
string input;
getline(cin, input);
add = stoi(input);
```

Comment: What do you expect the resulting `int*` to point to?

Comment: I want it to point to the address the user enters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert a string to `int` and then take its address:

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
int add = stoi(input);
int* ptr_to_add = &add;
```

Comment: @momo In that code change `i<input.length()` to `i < 1`.

Comment: That creates a new variable and then takes the address of that.